# How to decompress in node data that was compressed in ruby with gzip?

Tags: node.js, ruby, zlib

We have a ruby instance that sends a message to a node instance via rabbitmq (bunny and amqplib) like below:

```
{ :type => data, :data => msg }.to_bson.to_s
```

This seems to be going pretty well, but msg's are sometimes long and we are sending them across data centers. zlib would help a lot.

doing smth like this in the ruby sender:

```
encoded_data = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(msg).force_encoding(msg.encoding)
```

and then reading it inside node:

```
data = zlib.inflateSync(encoded_data)
```

returns

```
"\x9C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
```

Is what I'm trying to do possible?

Comment: you are forcing encoding on the deflated data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not a Ruby dev, so I will write the Ruby part in more or less pseudo code.

**Ruby code** (run online at https://repl.it/BoRD/0)

```
require 'json'
require 'zlib'

car = {:make => "bmw", :year => "2003"}

car_str = car.to_json

puts "car_str", car_str

car_byte = Zlib::Deflate.deflate(car_str)
# If you try to `puts car_byte`, it will crash with the following error:
# "\x9C" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8
#(repl):14:in `puts'
#(repl):14:in `puts'
#(repl):14:in `initialize'

car_str_dec = Zlib::Inflate.inflate(car_byte)

puts "car_str_dec", car_str_dec
# You can check that the decoded message is the same as the source.

# somehow send `car_byte`, the encoded bytes to RabbitMQ.
```

**Node code**

```
var zlib = require('zlib');

// somehow get the message from RabbitMQ.
var data = '...';

zlib.inflate(data, function (err, buffer) {
    if (err) {
        // Handle the error.
    } else {
       // If source didn't have any encoding,
       // no need to specify the encoding.
       console.log(buffer.toString());
    }
});
```

I also suggest you to stick with async functions in Node instead of their sync alternatives.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't work. Without force_encoding it crashes with error "from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8". With force_encoding it doesn't return anything.

Comment: I've expanded the example with a real working code. Please check.

Comment: @MB. have you got a chance to check my answer?